# How do I decrypt an AES-256 WinZip payload?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes

My goal is to decrypt an AES-256 encrypted file compatible with Winzip, produced by 7zip.
I want to use OpenSSL to decrypt the payload.

(normal zip file format. Not the 7z format)

I have the 39 byte binary payload.

The derived key matches with the one in 7zip.

Do I need to tell openssl the length of the key?
The openssl API expects an IV, but this type of encryption doesn't use one. How do I specify that there is no IV?

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

// gcc decrypt.c -lcrypto && ./a.out

int main()
{
  unsigned char key[100];
  unsigned char decout[100];
  unsigned char in[100];
  unsigned char dummy[100];
  unsigned char out[100];
  unsigned char* pass = "foo";
  unsigned char saltbuf[100];

  int passlen = strlen(pass);
  int saltlen = 16;
  int iter = 1000;
  int keylen = 32;
  const unsigned char* salt = saltbuf;
  FILE* fp = fopen("message", "rb");
  fread(saltbuf, sizeof(unsigned char), saltlen, fp);
  PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(pass, passlen, salt, saltlen, iter, keylen, key);

  fread(dummy, sizeof(unsigned char), 2, fp);
  fread(in, sizeof(unsigned char), 21, fp);
  int  msg_len=11;
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx;
  ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
  int declen=0;
  int declen2=0;
  printf("key:\n");
  BIO_dump_fp(stdout, key, keylen);
  EVP_DecryptInit(ctx, EVP_aes_256_ctr(), key, NULL);
  printf("input:\n");
  BIO_dump_fp(stdout, in, 11);
  EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, &decout, &declen, in, 11);
  printf("declen %i\n", declen);
  printf("declen2 %i\n", declen2);
  EVP_DecryptFinal(ctx, &decout + declen, &declen2);
  printf("decrypted:\n");
  BIO_dump_fp(stdout, &decout, 11);
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
}
```

Output:

There is a 32 byte key and an 11 byte encrypted message.

```
key:
0000 - fc 29 33 b3 64 6e 90 f7-ce b4 92 5b b7 cc d3 bc   .)3.dn.....[....
0010 - 55 ed b1 87 e4 57 07 2c-b4 a5 f8 77 b6 40 1c 62   U....W.,...w.@.b
input:
0000 - dc e2 26 62 ee 8a e9 71-51 86 14                  ..&b...qQ..
declen 11
declen2 0
decrypted:
0000 - e2 d7 09 96 53 45 9a dd-1e 44 a9                  ....SE...D.
```

background info: https://www.winzip.com/win/en/aes_info.html#encryption

**Update:**

I was able to decrypt it using the following code:
http://brg.a2hosted.com//oldsite/cryptography_technology/fileencrypt/index.php

I derived the key using `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1` from OpenSSL.

Still I would like to understand the difference and how to use OpenSSL to do the AES part.

Comment: AES-CTR requires an IV.

Comment: @JamesKPolk This is what 7zip uses to decrypt. It has CTR in the name but it may be different. https://github.com/kornelski/7z/blob/master/CPP/7zip/Crypto/WzAes.cpp#L177

Comment: See this [line](https://github.com/kornelski/7z/blob/master/CPP/7zip/Crypto/7zAes.cpp#L165)

Comment: @kelalaka: good find. They use the zero iv. Let's hope they don't encrypt two or more files with the same key.

Comment: @JamesKPolk nope. Look carefully, they first init to 0 then generate randomly.

Comment: @kelalaka: Uh-oh, there's no field to store the IV in the spec the OP linked to. Somethings missing.

Comment: @JamesKPolk did you see the [7zAes.h](https://github.com/kornelski/7z/blob/master/CPP/7zip/Crypto/7zAes.h#L58)?

Comment: @kelalaka: I meant stored in the encrypted file, so the decryptor can pick it up.

Comment: @kelalaka I'm looking at the Winzip compatible AES [WzAes.h](https://github.com/kornelski/7z/blob/master/CPP/7zip/Crypto/WzAes.h) which does not seem to use IV.

Comment: If we search [AesCtr_Code](https://github.com/kornelski/7z/search?q=AesCtr_Code&unscoped_q=AesCtr_Code)we will see that some it uses some IV's. I did not like the code, by the way, not easy to maintain.

Comment: @James - WinZip encryption has had problems over the years. Also see [Attacking and Repairing the WinZip Encryption Scheme](https://cryptosec.ucsd.edu/miscpapers/winzip-ccs04.pdf).

Comment: @jww interesting read. Thanks.